# Table with header row of normal height, remaining rows fill page vertically, table fills textwidth

Tags: tables, tabularx

Is there a way to achieve a table of width `\textwidth`, with the top row being of normal height, and the remaining rows filling the rest of the page in equal proportion?

I have this implemented but with an inexact fudge factor. I can imagine some implementation using a fancy tabular package (I was not able to make `tabularht` work) or something like the below where `\rowht` is set precisely based on `\arraystretch` or something and the height of the header, but I don't know how to do that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\def\rowht{0.935in}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X | X |}
  \hline
  A & B & C & D \\\hline
  & & &\\[\rowht]\hline
  & & &\\[\rowht]\hline
  & & &\\[\rowht]\hline
  & & &\\[\rowht]\hline
  & & &\\[\rowht]\hline
  & & &\\[\rowht]\hline
  & & &\\[\rowht]\hline
  & & &\\[\rowht]\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give a solution with the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{showframe}
%\renewcommand*{\ShowFrameColor}{\color{red}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\def\rowht{%
  \dimexpr
    (
      \textheight
       - \baselineskip                   % height of first row
       - 4pt * \value{rowcount}          % rowsep sizes
       - 0.4pt * ( \value{rowcount} - 1) % hrule sizes
    ) / ( \value{rowcount} - 1 )
  \relax
}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={|X|X|X|X|},
  hlines,
  row{2-Z} = {\rowht}, % Z stands for the last row
}
  A & B & C & D \\
    &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   \\
\end{tblr}

\newpage

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={|X|X|X|X|},
  hlines,
  row{2-Z} = {\rowht},
}
  A & B & C & D \\
    &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So new I did not have it in my distribution. Looks exciting. Thanks

Comment: You can update your TeXlive or MikTeX to get it.